# Feature detection for windows phone?

Tags: c#, xna, camera, windows-phone-7.1, face-detection

I'd like to know how to create arbitrary image detection using the following library: http://facedetectwp7.codeplex.com/ . In the description it states that any object can be detected if the models are added to the project. Does anyone know how to create these models? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is an XML file that is created as a result of training a Haar Classifer. The XML file that is included with the library is the default file that's used by OpenCV.

To create a model file for a custom set of objects, you'll need a large set of positive images (images that have the objects), and negative images (without the object).

You'll then "train" the classifier on these two image sets, and this will produce a single xml file.

Check out [this link](http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/create-your-own-haar-classifier-for-detecting-objects-in-opencv/) for more info.